# "Unknown alias" error with SharePoint incoming e-mail

Tags: email, sharepoint

After backing up and restoring a site collection, incoming e-mail for the site collection no longer works.

In the ULS log, the following message appears (where mailalias is the name of the e-mail alias):

`The Incoming E-Mail service has completed a batch.  The elapsed time was 00:00:00.  The service processed 1 message(s) in total.  Errors occurred processing 1 message(s): Message ID: <0b7d0469-8bdc-4d9c-9834-aada5c458037@server>   The following aliases were unknown: mailalias`

In this case incoming e-mail for the alias is associated with an event handler/receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the [stsadm -o refreshdms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288589.aspx) command. To fix the error for a particular site, use [stsadm -o refreshsitedms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287976.aspx).

Other details located at the blog of [Sameer Surve](http://blogs.msdn.com/sameersurve/archive/2008/09/09/email-enabled-document-libraries-stop-receiving-emails.aspx).